# filling missing date for each group in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, date, group

I have a very large dataframe(df) with date,id, x columns.

The date column is formatted as date (y.m.d) and has value for some days scatteredly.Each group in the id column has a different start and end date.

tl;dr my goal is to fill the missing date for each group by adding a row with an empty value for x column.
df

| date | id | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22.02.02 | A | 26 |
| 22.02.06 | A | 45 |
| 22.02.08 | A | 46 |
| 22.02.05 | B | 37 |
| 22.02.09 | B | 82 |
| 22.02.12 | B | 56 |
| 22.01.13 | C | 61 |
| 22.01.17 | C | 90 |
| 22.01.20 | C | 43 |
| 22.01.23 | C | 12 |

my desired output df:

| date | id | X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22.02.02 | A | 26 |
| 22.02.03 | A |  |
| 22.02.04 | A |  |
| 22.02.05 | A |  |
| 22.02.06 | A | 45 |
| 22.02.07 | A |  |
| 22.02.08 | A | 46 |
| 22.02.05 | B | 37 |
| 22.02.06 | B |  |
| 22.02.07 | B |  |
| 22.02.08 | B |  |
| 22.02.09 | B | 82 |
| 22.02.10 | B |  |
| 22.02.11 | B |  |
| 22.02.12 | B | 56 |
| 22.01.13 | C | 61 |
| 22.01.14 | C |  |
| 22.01.15 | C |  |
| 22.01.16 | C |  |
| 22.01.17 | C | 90 |
| 22.01.18 | C |  |
| 22.01.19 | C |  |
| 22.01.20 | C | 43 |
| 22.01.21 | C |  |
| 22.01.22 | C |  |
| 22.01.23 | C | 12 |

I do not know how to solve this kind of questions, what is the most efficient way to solve this?!

Here my code which does not give me the result:

```
     df_output <- df %>%
       group_by(id) %>%
        complete(df$date = seq(min(df$date), max(df$date), by = 
        "1 day"), fill = list(number = 0))
```

I am new to R and using dplyr.

Comment: Please share an example of your data with `dput(head(df))`.

Answer (score 3):

- We can try this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df$date <- lubridate::as_date(df$date)

df |> group_by(id) |>
      complete(date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = "1 day"), fill = list(number = 0))
```

Comment: Thanks , however I get this error Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number.

Answer (score 1):

First we have to transform to date format to use `complete`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  complete(date = seq(min(date), max(date), by = 
                           "1 day"), fill = list(number = 0))
```

```
   id    date           X
   <chr> <date>     <int>
 1 A     2022-02-02    26
 2 A     2022-02-03    NA
 3 A     2022-02-04    NA
 4 A     2022-02-05    NA
 5 A     2022-02-06    45
 6 A     2022-02-07    NA
 7 A     2022-02-08    46
 8 B     2022-02-05    37
 9 B     2022-02-06    NA
10 B     2022-02-07    NA
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using the package `padr` with `pad` and `fill_by_value` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(padr)
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%y.%m.%d")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  pad(., interval = "day") %>%
  fill_by_value(., value = NA)
#> # A tibble: 26 × 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>    date       id        X
#>    <date>     <chr> <int>
#>  1 2022-02-02 A        26
#>  2 2022-02-03 A        NA
#>  3 2022-02-04 A        NA
#>  4 2022-02-05 A        NA
#>  5 2022-02-06 A        45
#>  6 2022-02-07 A        NA
#>  7 2022-02-08 A        46
#>  8 2022-02-05 B        37
#>  9 2022-02-06 B        NA
#> 10 2022-02-07 B        NA
#> # … with 16 more rows
#> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>